# unable to change default django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I was going through the tutorial of Django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/
At the end they asked us to change the name of default webpage template from "Django Administration" to anything else by following steps.
1) Copy base_site.html from default folder of django to the admin directory specified in TEMPLATE_DIRS.
Currently my TEMPLATE_DIRS looks like -

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
"/home/mysite/polls/mytemplates"
)
```

I have also copied the admin template directory to /home/mysite/polls/mytemplates

So the structure is something like this
 /home/mysite/polls/mytemplates/admin
where admin folder contains base.html and base_site.html

I have  edited the title in base_site.html file but still when i run django it shows me default template title.

Can someone tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Can you check if `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` comes first in the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting.

Comment: @tuxcanfly Yes. it does. Check below                                TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

Comment: You are missing a comma: `"/home/mysite/polls/mytemplates",`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Added comma. Still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your template directory should not have your application name in it. Django will automatically add any directory called `templates` that is part of any app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. This is why your custom admin template isn't working.

The first thing you should do is rename `/home/mysite/polls/mytemplates` to `templates`:

```
mv /home/mysite/polls/mytemplates /home/mysite/polls/templates
```

Next, you should have:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/mysite/templates',)
```

Then, your admin templates should be in `/home/mysite/templates/admin/`

As for the comma : a single string in parenthesis is just a string, but with a comma it becomes a tuple. The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is a tuple, which is why you need that extra comma:

```
>>> a = ('hello')
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> a = ('hello',)
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: I renamed it to templates


    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/home/mysite/templates',
)

Admin folder lies in /home/mysite/templates/.
Still it is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The issue was with the single quote that i had in my site name. So had to enclose the entire site name in Double quotes instead of one